# Is there a function to get the max of two values in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the maximum value of 2 Integer (or 2 float).

I know I can do it with a IF function like this: 
    IF (column1 > column2, column1, column2)

however I was wondering if a function to do that exists or if there is a plan to add that kind of function in the future.

In MySQL there is the GREATER function that can do that. Example: GREATER(column1, column2).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

BigQuery supports

```
GREATEST(expr1, expr2, ...)
```

which returns the largest argument. I've filed an internal bug to get this added to our public documentation.

Comment: The function doesnt seem to be working if one of the vals is null. Is there any way to ignore null values in the columns?

Comment: The documentation is now available at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#greatest

Comment: Somewhat related, but if anyone is looking for the *smallest* of several values, the function is `LEAST` as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#least).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't currently a function to return the greater of two values in BigQuery. If you end up needing to compute the value a lot in a single query, you can always get the greater value in a subselect.

For example:

```
SELECT gr 
FROM (
    SELECT IF(column1 > column2, column1, column2) as gr 
    FROM [my_dataset.my_table])
WHERE gr > 27
GROUP BY gr
```

Comment: I'm guessing this answer was posted before the `GREATEST()` function was added to BQ. Could you update your answer to clarify? A Google Search for `bigquery get greater of 2 values` shows your answer in the "Featured Snippet", which led me to believe there was no function for this.