# How to get a webhook from harbor using alertmanger?

Tags: webhooks, harbor, prometheus-alertmanager

Suppose I have enabled webhook on harbor

[image: 1]

And... How to get a webhook from harbor using alertmanger?

Initially, I tried to do it through vmalert and collecting metrics from harbor. In this way I did it. But it must be done through harbor's webhook.
Accordingly, can alertmanager receive webhooks?
If so, how is it done correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Alertmanager is usually the one who triggers webhooks, but generally it could receive one, if syntax of payload would be appropriate.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25529731/21363224) is example how to trigger alertmanager with curl.