# BigQuery:How to calculate average across the row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A. | 55 | 50 | 45 |
| B. | 30 | 20 | 25 |

I want to know how I can calculate max across a row in BigQuery and thus return the result:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A. | 55 |
| B. | 30 |

So for A the max across the rest of the rows will be 55 and for B average across the rows will be 30

Comment: Sorry, are you looking for simple `select columnA, (columnB+columnC+columnD)/3`?

Comment: Sorry, I feel stupid now. Can you tell me how to get the max value from the row?

Comment: [`GREATEST(expr1, expr2, ...) `](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25529731/21363224)

Comment: You want the average or the max ?

Comment: Thanks, GREATEST with CASE WHEN worked perfectly to get the greatest value from the row with the corresponding column name

Comment: @SelVazi At first I thought AVG would work but that was not the case so I switched to MAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the max value across columns you can use `GREATEST()` :

```
select ColumnA, GREATEST(ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD) as MAX
from mytable
```

If you want to get the maximum from all the rows, then you can do it as follows :

```
select ColumnA, GREATEST(max(ColumnB), max(ColumnC), max(ColumnD)) as MAX
from mytable
group by ColumnA
```